# User form to define data validation list range excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have a button that once clicked loops through a DV list and prints each selection as a PDF document, ideally id like to be able to choose the length of the DV list via a Userform EG I select option one on the userform which sets the DV list range to 50 cells.

Sub Button_Click6()

```
Dim cell                  As Excel.Range
Dim rgDV                  As Excel.Range
Dim DV_Cell               As Excel.Range
Dim LA As Boolean



Set ws = ActiveSheet

LAform.Show
    Select Case LAform.Tag
        Case 0
            LA = False     'FALSE FOR Richmond, TRUE FOR Kingston
        Case 1
            LA = True
    End Select


If LA = True Then
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Validation.Add xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
xlBetween, Formula1:=Worksheets("Data").Range("B4:B56")

ElseIf LA = False Then
ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Validation.Add xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=Worksheets("Data").Range("B56:B104")
    'enter name and select folder for file
' start in current workbook folder

Set DV_Cell = Range("B1")

Set rgDV = Application.Range(Mid$(DV_Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2))
For Each cell In rgDV.Cells
    DV_Cell.Value = cell.Value
    Call PDFActiveSheet2
Next
End If
End Sub
```

The problem i get is an Application or object defined error After the If and else if trying to set the dv range.

Thanks.

Comment: which line exactly does the error occur on? And is `LA` populating as you would expect?

Comment: LA is working fine its the IF formulas that dont work off the back of that.

ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Validation.Add xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
xlBetween, Formula1:=Worksheets("Data").Range("B4:B56")

Comment: I think the code would be better written if you just show the `UserForm` on the button click. Then have two buttons on the user form that the user can click for the specific option. Then put the code behind each button to print the list you want. Also, there's no need for data validation here. Just loop through the specific cells you want to work with. Unless you need the validation for another step later on.

Comment: Sorry i havn't explained myself very well, the DV list is needed as the active sheet changes on each selection from the list it works as a statement for each customer. And DV is a customer list.

I see what you mean with putting it behind each button, i will give that a go. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Button_Click6()

    Dim cell                  As Excel.Range
    Dim rgDV                  As Excel.Range
    Dim DV_Cell               As Excel.Range
    Dim La As Boolean


 Laform.Show
    Select Case Laform.Tag
        Case 0
            La = False     'FALSE FOR Richmond, TRUE FOR Kingston
        Case 1
            La = True
    End Select

Set DV_Cell = Range("B1")

Set rgDV = Application.Range(Mid$(DV_Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2))
For Each cell In rgDV.Cells
    DV_Cell.Value = cell.Value
    Call PDFActiveSheet2
Next

End Sub
```

With the advice i was given i put the code into the user form buttons which sets the DV list range, while the macro runs as it now should.

```
Private Sub Borough1_Click()
Range("B1:E1").Select
    With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Data!$B$57:$B$107"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
    End With
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Range("B1:E1").Select
    With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=Data!$B$4:$B$56"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
    End With
 Me.Hide
End Sub
```